# Feasible to assign 2 processors out of 4 to a vm running windows 7

Tags: windows-7, virtualization, processing, vmware-workstation

I currently have windows 7 running on my machine. I need a second version of windows 7 to run as a virtual machine. I have 4 GBs of RAM and 4 processors. I've been doing some research and see a number of articles arguing against the use of more then 1 processor for vms.

Windows 7 is essential and it requires a lot of processing power so 1 processor is not enough.

Is it feasible to increase this to 2 processors?

Comment: Ok, sorry about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. Virtualization is often used in data centers to better distribute loads across different applications that would otherwise require separate physical servers, reducing cost and maximizing throughput with less hardware by allowing other applications to utilize otherwise unused CPU time instead of letting it go to waste on separate servers.

I don't see why you can't or shouldn't use multiple processors or cores for virtualization.  In fact, you can set a lower CPU priority for the VM in the host operating system, so that the VM doesn't interfere with the host OS if it needs more processing capacity.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is perfectly fine to assign multiple processors to virtual machines.

I have never seen any article arguing against the use of multiple physical processors, and I wouldnt take any article that did seriously.  One of the fundamental principals and main advantages of virtualization is the ability to assign hardware resources to a virtual machine.  The use of multiple processors - or fractions of - is one of the most widely used features in virtual machine managers.